# Calling async function befrore server start to listen

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, bluebird

I've node app and I want to call to function before the server is start,my questions are:

1. what is the recommended why to do it ?
2. does that can have an issue (that I call to some async function before the server is up)

Btw I use bluebird

This is my code

```
//This is the function which I want to call before
    process.beforeProc();
    //Before I start the following server
    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log('listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
        }
    });






**UPDATE**
The preProcess look like following 


exports.beforeProc= function () {

    run.validate(function (err) {

        console.log(err);
        process.exit(1);
    });

    Parser.parse().then(function (con) {
        //Cache the path values to serve new requests
        if (typeof require.cache.persist === 'undefined') {
            require.cache.persist = {};
        }
        require.cache.persist.con = con;
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

.....

Comment: is `beforeProc` asynchronous? does `createServer` depend on the results of `beforeProc`?

Comment: @dm03514 - yes it contains inside some method which use promises...

Comment: Then return a promise, and use a `then` chain to call `listen()` only when the `beforeProc` function has completed

Comment: @adeneo - can you please provide example how its recommended to do it ?

Comment: That depends entirely on what the `beforeProc` function looks like, but I could whip up some general example just returning a promise?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/atwhL7xq/

Comment: @adeneo - beforeProc is method which call to other method i'll update my question in 2 min...

Comment: @adeneo - please see my update,how should I return promise when I use the beforeProc like following...

Comment: @adeneo - my method is a bit more complicated to use promise....

Comment: You could always just use a regular callback if you don't want to use promises, something like -> https://jsfiddle.net/nbfb5L66/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have 50 rep so I made an answer:

Does process.beforeProc() have a callback?
If so you can do it like this:

```
process.beforeProc(function() {
    // Once the beforeProc loaded it will return the callback, so whats
    // in here
    http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log('listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Agreed. You will need to put the server creation function into the callback.